# displayquote environment question

Tags: csquotes

I haven't found a proper thread in forum, nor fully understand directions in the csquote package manual.
How can I make some text stay in the left side as a "prequote", while the rest of it would align independently, i.e. like this:

[image]
Instead of this:

[image]
My source code looks like that, what should I change:

```
\begin{displayquote}
\5.4711 To give the essence of proposition means to give the essence of all description, therefore the essence of the world.
\end{displayquote}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It would be nice to have the full minimal working example (MWE), i.e., including documentclass, begin/end document, and preamble with required packages. Then, we can comprehend better what the exact problem is.

Comment: Also, is the 5.4711 the cite key or something along those lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a first attempt, I would suggest

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\renewcommand{\mkbegdispquote}[2]{%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.1\textwidth}#2\end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\textwidth}%
}
\renewcommand{\mkenddispquote}[2]{\end{minipage}}
\renewcommand{\mkcitation}[1]{#1}

\begin{document}
\begin{displayquote}[5.4711]
To give the essence of proposition means to give the essence of 
all description, therefore the essence of the world.
\end{displayquote}

\end{document}
```

The first two `\renewcommand` commands define the appearance of the quote. You may want to adjust it and make sure that it fits into your document. Note that this version ignores the `punct` parameter which may be important for you (Search the documentation for `mkbegdispquote` for further information).

The third `renewcommand` removes the parentheses around the citation key.